# Alpha version of my Android app not available in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, alpha

I need to test some features of my app like the "In App Billing" service so I published it in an Alpha version in Google Play, I filled all the required fields, I added the testers Gmail account, the app is signed and its version is higher than the Beta/Production version.

Since yesterday in the Alpha section of the Google Play Console I can see the app as published, but when I go to the Play Store the app doesn't appear, trying to get it from the provided link it says that the app isn't available because it has not been published or I can't access to it with my account.

I have verified the accounts signed up in the console and all is right, am I forgotting any step? Did I do anything wrong? Any help would be really appreciated, there is more than one day since the app is published and I cannot test it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I thought that you can not access alpha-release as the alpha-tester. But, you can not access your beta-release?

Answer (score 8):

alpha applications are directly not accessible in play store you have to get link from developer account, where your apk is published there is link as manage testers click on that you will get link and only user who is member of that group can access it through registered email link will look like : https://play.google.com/apps/testing/uk.co.xxxxx.xxxxx)
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: I thought the app become visible in Google Play, so thank you @Pavan, but the app isn't available using the link provided by the Google Play Developer console, I tried today again and nothing has changed.

Comment: it only accessible to user who added in test group and when accessing this link he must be logged in browser and play store account with email which is added in test group

Comment: Yes I know, as I said in my post I verified that the Gmail accounts was added to the console as a tester. I'm logged in with one of the tester accounts in the browser.

Comment: I have a similar scenario, whereby my app shows as a published closed-alpha build. I've added my alpha testers. Why aren't they getting the invite notification? Is it customary to have to manually email them the opt-in URL as well as add them via Manage Testers. Seems odd if I do..

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who were installing **Android TV** app and had the same error as OP. Open your test link

> `https://play.google.com/apps/testing/{package}`

on a desktop computer with account logged in on tv. Then you will be asked to participate in tests, and after acception you will be redirected to your alpha google play website. From here (on desktop pc) you can install it on your TV.

Answer (score 0):

We missed the "Choose a testing method" step inside the APK menu option, thank you very much